# java executing bash script, error=26 Text file busy

Tags: java, linux, bash

I've got a java code that is writing a Linux bash script out, then doing a chmod to add execute permission, then trying to execute it.  I'm getting an IOException during the start of the process saying error=26, Text file busy.  <s>**I've verified that the file is finished being written and the stream was closed.**</s>  The chmod works fine, but I keep getting this error.

I've noticed that if I run a debugger and step through the code, it doesn't get the error, so clearly there is a timing issue involved.  How can I make sure the chmod is done before I try to execute the bash script?  I'd like to avoid non-reliable solutions like adding Thread.sleep(10000), and "hacky" things like putting the execution in a try/catch block inside a loop that tries until it succeeds.

I have a fair amount of code wrapping the startup of the process with listening threads, etc., but here is a simplified version of what it is doing (tried this code also and it has same result):

```
String[] cmd1 = {"/bin/chmod", "750", postFile };
new ProcessBuilder(cmd1).redirectErrorStream(true).start().waitFor();
String[] cmd2 = { postFile };
new ProcessBuilder(cmd2).redirectErrorStream(true).start().waitFor();
```

Every time after execution, the "postFile" has the correct 750 permissions, but it has not executed (due to the IOException).

Comment: Could we have some code? Like the way you execute your chmod? Thanks

Comment: Double-check that you do not have the file opened in multiple locations.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had the same problem and there was a totally unrelated and disposed of class which had opened the file but not closed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure it is the chmod that is responsible for the subsequent error?  Could you check that you definitely **close** the output file before you try to run it?

If you do close it then I'm at a loss why chmod should cause that error, but you could avoid the need to run chmod by using your shell to run the script:

`String[] cmd = {"bash", postfile };`

Comment: I tried your suggestion "String[] cmd2 = {"/bin/sh", "-c", postFile};, I get the same error.  I am going back and checking that streams are closed again just to be sure.

Comment: You were right.  The class I was using to unzip the file was NOT closing it's stream.  Doh!

Answer (score 10):

For future reference, it may have been caused by an unclosed stream in this particular case, but setting permissions on a file immediately followed by running the file can cause this error too:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "...": error=26, Text file busy
```

It is a [probable bug in JDK](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068370). In my case, it was caused by this snippet of code

```
Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Paths.get(scriptPath), set(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_EXECUTE, PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ));
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(scriptPath).directory(workingDir);
processBuilder.start();
```

even if nothing was editing the script file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related but usually you need to get or redirect the ErrorStream and the InputStream (I usually get them in a ResponseStreamReader that I create, don't know about the redirecting choice).

Comment: I have code to do that and a separate thread that's listening.  I only posted a simplified version of the code, because I have a whole class dedicated to it.  FYI, I do redirect the error into the output stream for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

In my service file in `/etc/systemd/system/` I have directed outputs to log files:
`StandardOutput=file:/home/pi/ApplicationLogs/application_l_debug.log`
`StandardError=file:/home/pi/ApplicationLogs/application_l_error.log`

The error message disappeared when I changed permissions on the ApplicationLogs directory to write permissions to all
(`chmod a+w ApplicationLogs`)