# Scala, Akka --> Write out shell script, then execute it within Actor --> IOException Cannot run program Text file busy 26

Tags: java, scala, shell, akka

Ok. So the following code works.  And, it works within an Akka actor.  However, when scaling up the number of threads (i.e. few hundred), it crashes with text file busy.

Process is.  I write a shell script to disk, then set its execute bit.  Immediately after, I run the script by way of ProcessBuilder.

```
import better.files._ // uses nio

// this occurs in an actor, many are running in parallel
val f = File(pathToFile)
f.overwrite(contentsofScript)
f.addPermission(PosixFilePermissions.OWNER_EXECUTE)
val p = Process(pathToFile)
p.! // execute IT!
```

Every process points to a unique and random location (pathToFile) in the file system.

I'm stumped as to why the code doesn't scale well.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=26, Text file busy
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 26 more
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345660/java-executing-bash-script-error-26-text-file-busy) describes bug in JDK or possibily unclosed I/O streams.  I was using traditional PrintWriter with .close() and .flush() calls before launching the process.  I have tried opening and reading contents of the files before running the process (in hopes to close resources).   I moved to `better.files._` hoping that it would better handle resources.
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

`ulimit -n` gives 65000 (max open files).

Comment: what about limit on maximum user processes? `ulimit -u`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. I'm an idiot.  This assertion I made was false:

Every process points to a unique and random location (pathToFile) in the file system.

Fixed corner case in my code where this didn't occur (was running thousands of threads, there was duplicated random UUID generated, thus duplicate processes touching same directory)

EDIT: Above was only partially related...

There may be a JDK bug (courtesy of [java executing bash script, error=26 Text file busy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345660/java-executing-bash-script-error-26-text-file-busy))

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068370

.. the following code change solved the issue ..

```
val p = Process(Seq("bash", pathToFile))
p.!
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you are encountering a race condition, where the content your write to the file is not synced when you execute said file.

I thought about this when reading the first comment on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16764967/7760212

Then I looked at `better-files` which seems clean in terms of closing files after writing.  However, it seems that the options passed to `java.nio.Files.*` could be a bit safer in your case. I would suggest trying to pass non-default value for the `openOptions` parameter of the `overwrite` call.  You can read about those options here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardOpenOption.html, but I would recommend adding `StandardOpenOption.SYNC` to the default set of `better-files`.`